# Understanding modulus

Tags: modulus

I don't really understand how modulus division works. I was calculating 5 % 6 and wound up with 5 and I don't understand why.
I understand modulus without decimal values. E. G 16%3 = 5 r 1.

Comment: 5 = 0x6 + 5 so the remainder is 5.

Comment: Thats your problem 5 % 6, shouldnt it be 6 % 5?

Comment: This has nothing to do with java.

Comment: What don't you understand about it?  Do you know what the modulus operator means?  6 goes into 5 exactly 0 times, with a remainder of 5.

Comment: By the way: a question about mathematics is not on topic here and should be asked on the [Stack Exchange for maths](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, and you can find an explanation of this very quickly and easily by searching the web.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: Modulus (MOD) Operator Repeated Sequences: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2240-creating-repeated-sequences-with-the-modulus-mod-operator.htm

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your calculation `5 % 6` is that it will ALWAYS give you remainder 5. If you tried `6 % 5`, that will give you 1 for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a programming question, as modulus is a mathematical operator not at all unique to Java or any programming language, but 5 mod 6 = 5 as it is the remainder after dividing by 6 (5 < 6 so the remainder *is* 5). 6 mod 5 = 1, as 6 > 5, so you subtract 5, then you are left with 1 and 1 < 6.

If it helps, here is a pseudocode illustration of modulus (for positive integers):

```
integer mod(integer a, integer b) {
    if a < b:
        return a
    else:
        return mod(a - b, b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`num1 % num2`

The modulus operator divides num1 by num2 *as integers* (in other words, all results of division are rounded **down** to the nearest whole number) and outputs the remainder. In your case, 5/6 = 0 with a remainder of 5.

Another way of expressing the remainder is:
`num1 = x*num2 + R`

Where x is the result of the integer division `num1/num2` and R is the remainder, which is the output of the modules operator. Again in your case, `5 = 0*6 + 5`.

Answer (score 0):

Modulus operator is similar to the "remainder", but there are a technicalities that make it different when negative numbers are involved.

However, for your example, think of 5 % 6 as "the remainder of 5 divided by 6"  Read left to right, just like division.